# Development of mathematics in Europe between 550-1050 A.D

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I'm trying to search for any kind of development in the mathematics (science, astronomy, even astrology or other kind of early studies that envolve any kind of math) expecially in early england and in the carolingian empire.

The problem I have is that it seams that math died in there: every work seems to be related to arabic, or chinese or indian work in the area. In science I'm looking and nothing seems to appears. So I've the main question:

> *Is there any reference, article, name of scientis of mathematician, book,  page, etc. that can bring contributions to math history in england or in the carolingian empire between 550 and 1050 A.D? Even the e-mail of someone who is a expeciallist in the area could work as a fruitfull answer*

thanks for future answers or critics.

Comment: will spain do? it is technically europe and there is a lot of mathematical writing there, especially close to the end of the period you are describing?

Comment: For math, see the fundamental work og M.Clagett: [Archimedes in the M.A.](https://www.google.it/search?q=clagett+archimedes+in+the+middle+ages&oq=clagett+archimedes&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.5789j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active#q=clagett+archimedes+in+the+middle+ages&safe=active&tbm=bks) (many volumes): but I think that the the time-span covered is later than yours...

Comment: @gt6989b i think spain was a very little part of the carolingian empire and in a brief moment also. They ware dominated by muçulmans in the period who develped math very intensively. So I think doesn't. The propose is to search for non-arab and non-chinese math developers. Even monk's could work.

Comment: I'll see your references @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you very much. Sorry for my english I'm from brazil.

Comment: You can see Anthony Lo Bello's editions of [early translations of Euclid](https://www.google.it/search?q=Anthony+Lo+Bello+Gerard+of+Cremona%27s+Translation+of+the+Commentary+of+Al-Nayrizi+on+Book+I+of+Euclid%27s+Elements+of+Geometry&oq=Anthony+Lo+Bello+Gerard+of+Cremona%27s+Translation+of+the+Commentary+of+Al-Nayrizi+on+Book+I+of+Euclid%27s+Elements+of+Geometry&aqs=chrome..69i57.3583j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active#safe=active&tbm=bks&q=Anthony+Lo+Bello+Gerard+of+Cremona+Translation+of+the+Commentary+of+Al-Nayrizi+on+Book+I+of+Euclid's+Elements+of+Geometry).

Comment: Maybe useful: Edward Grant (editor), [Mathematics and Its Applications to Science and Natural Philosophy in the Middle Ages](https://books.google.it/books?id=6u5fOB7EXcsC&pg=PR%) (1987).

Comment: More "narrative": Nancy Marie Brown, [The Abacus and the Cross: The Story of the Pope Who Brought the Light of Science to the Dark Ages](https://books.google.it/books?id=vwy5B9ZXMh4C&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

Comment: Btw, there is a History of Science and Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is believed that [Alcuin of York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcuin) (c. 735 - 804 AD) is the author of [Propositiones ad Acuendos Juvenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositiones_ad_Acuendos_Juvenes), a collection of 53 recreational problems, some of them well known.

Another topic to look into is calendar mathematics, which was important in this time period. According to [Victor Katz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0134689526), Charlemagne recommended that Church Schools include the mathematics necessary for Easter computation.

Comment: If you stop your quest around 1050, i.e., just before the universities of Paris, Oxford, Bologan, etc. were born, just before the building of cathedrals (who used some geometry), the answer is that there are very few documents in general and almost nothing in mathematics...

Answer (score 2):

For mathematics to have died in England it should have been alive there in the first place - I wonder what you have in mind to back up this claim of yours. This being said, see Howson's book *A History of Mathematics Education in England*. In the preface hw writes:

- "We cannot be certain exactly when mathematics first was taught in England,
  but Bede  (674-735) in his *Ecclesiastical History* tells how Theodore,
  Archbishop of Canterbury in the late seventh century, and his deacon, 
  Hadrian, gathered a crowd of disciples . . . and . . . taught them the
  art of ecclesiastical poetry, astronomoy and arithmetic."

Since Greek mathematics had fallen into oblivion in the Roman Empire, all that was available until the discovery of Arabic manuscripts were the Books by Boethius, which consisted of a few propositions from Euclid's first book and parts of the Arithmetic of Nikomachus.

Comment: Very nice answer (+1) I'm looking for the cited reference. In my research, at some point, I also started to wonder if math was ever a topic between the early england after roman 'society'.